# Unix Processes - compile and run c program

Tags: c, unix, process

Create a parent process that gets from the command line n arguments arg1, arg2, ... , argn. arg1 is the name to a source C, arg2 is the name of the executable file results from compile arg1, and arg3, ... , argn are arguments to start.

The parent compiles arg1 and creates the executable arg2, after that runs it into a son process.

I tried to solve the problem, using some examples, but I didn't really understand them, so the program is not working. I really need some help...

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   char com[200];
   int p;
   p=fork();
   strcpy(com,"gcc -o prog.c");
   strcat(com,argv[1]);

   if(p==0){
       if(WEXITSTATUS(system(com))==0)
          execl("./prog.c","./prog.c",argv[3],argv[4],argv[5],NULL);
   }

   wait(0);
   exit(0);

   return 0;
}
```

The C program I want to use, reads some input data from two files and stores data into another file.

Comment: "the program is not working" is not a question…

Comment: You really do have to ask a question.

Comment: Look at the result of your second `strcat` and you'll see it's malformed. Also, you try to execute the C program rather than the compiled output.

Comment: You'll confuse most people if you end your executables with the `.c` suffix as your code seems to be doing.  Conventionally, `.c` is used to mark the file as a C source file, not as a program compiled from C code.

Answer (score 1):

This code more or less does what you say your program should do.  In particular, it uses `argv[2]` as the program name.  It uses `snprintf()` to avoid overflows with long arguments (but doesn't verify that it didn't overrun).  It prints various status messages — partly as a debugging aid, partly to give meaning to the various parts of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int p;

    if (argc != 6)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s source program file1 file2 file3\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }

    if ((p = fork()) == 0)
    {
        char com[200];
        snprintf(com, sizeof(com), "gcc -o %s %s", argv[2], argv[1]);
        if (system(com) == 0)
        {
            printf("Compilation of %s successful\n", argv[2]);
            fflush(0);
            execl(argv[2], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], argv[5], (char *)NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute %s\n", argv[2]);
            return(1);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Compilation of %s from %s failed\n", argv[2], argv[1]);
        return(1);
    }

    int status;

    wait(&status);
    printf("Compilation and execution of %s yielded status %d\n",
           argv[2], WEXITSTATUS(status));
    return 0;
}
```

When this file is named `gc.c` and is compiled to make `gc`, it can be run as:

```
$ ./gc gc.c ./gc2 gc.c gc.c gc.c
Compilation of ./gc2 successful
Usage: ./gc2 source program file1 file2 file3
Compilation and execution of ./gc2 yielded status 1
$
```

The usage message from `gc2` is correct; the program expects 6 arguments, not the 4 it is given by the program.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the manual of `exec` which will tell you how to run exec to fork another process that behaves according to the specification. This code can help you how to pass on variables to a child process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for fork */
#include <sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* for wait */

int main()
{
    /*Spawn a child to run the program.*/
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if (pid==0) { /* child process */
        static char *argv[]={"echo","Foo is my name.",NULL};
        execv("/bin/echo",argv);
        exit(127); /* only if execv fails */
    }
    else { /* pid!=0; parent process */
        waitpid(pid,0,0); /* wait for child to exit */
    }
    return 0;
}
```